# ActiveAdmin & devise user registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I'm new to rails and ActiveAdmin. I'm trying to create a sign up page for ActiveAdmin. 
First, I `rails generate devise:views` 
Second, I change my routes.rb:

```
# not devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config  .
devise_for :admin_users
```

However, I realized that my new created sign_up view (app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb) doesn't have a controller. The only  controller that I have is app/controllers/concerns/application_controller.rb
Here is my routes:

```
    new_admin_user_session GET        /admin/login(.:format)                  active_admin/devise/sessions#new
        admin_user_session POST       /admin/login(.:format)                  active_admin/devise/sessions#create
destroy_admin_user_session DELETE|GET /admin/logout(.:format)                 active_admin/devise/sessions#destroy
   new_admin_user_password GET        /admin/password/new(.:format)           active_admin/devise/passwords#new
  edit_admin_user_password GET        /admin/password/edit(.:format)          active_admin/devise/passwords#edit
       admin_user_password PATCH      /admin/password(.:format)               active_admin/devise/passwords#update
                           PUT        /admin/password(.:format)               active_admin/devise/passwords#update
                           POST       /admin/password(.:format)               active_admin/devise/passwords#create
                admin_root GET        /admin(.:format)                        admin/dashboard#index
...
```

How can I create a new route for admin_user sign up page that I can go `localhost:3000/admins/sign_up`.

Comment: Go through this link for better understanding https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run

```
rails generate devise:controllers admins
```

and modify your routes.rb

```
devise_for :admins, path: 'admins', controllers: { sessions: "admins/sessions" }
```

for more info see [this page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models)

If you haven't already, I would recommend you set up the devise for users first.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Shouldn't it be `admin_users` instead of `admins`? Still, it didn't work. I don't see admin/sign_up anywhere in my routes. How did you guys do this? I need the admin to be able to sign up himself.

Comment: That just depends on the name of your model, yes you can use admin_user instead of admin. I didn't do this but the sign_up path comes from the registrations controller, so perhaps you could try changing your routes file to include that? 
    'devise_for :admins, path: 'admins', controllers: { sessions: "admins/sessions", registrations: "admins/registrations" }'    and then a namespaced route like  'devise_scope :admin do
    get "register", to: "devise/registraions#new" end'